# How to store value generated from a ViewController using NSCoding in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following variables from "ScoreHistory.swift":

```
// ScoreHistory.swift

class ScoreHistory: NSObject, NSCoding {

var datePlayed: NSDate
var totalScore: Int
var totalAnswered: Int
var totalDuration: Int
var gameStatus: String
```

In my QuizViewController, I have the following variables:

```
// QuizViewController.swift

var datePlayed = NSDate()
var totalScore = 0
var totalAnswered = 0
var totalDuration = 0
var gameStatus: String?
```

After each game session, the user might get the following: (to be displayed in the “ScoreViewController”)

```
// Example data

datePlayed: (date today)
totalScore: 10
totalAnswered: 15
totalDuration: 1 min. 3 sec.
gameStatus: Exam Finished
```

I need to get the above data from QuizViewController to store to "ScoreHistory.swift"
I need the data to be displayed in ScoreViewController.swift:

```
// ScoreViewController.swift

class ScoreViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

// in viewDidLoad()

if let score = score {

    navigationItem.title = score.datePlayed.description
    datePlayedLabel.text = score.datePlayed.description
    totalScoreLabel.text   = score.totalScore.description
    totalAnsweredLabel.text   = score.totalAnswered.description
    totalDurationLabel.text   = score.totalDuration.description
    gameStatusLabel.text   = score.gameStatus
}
```

How do I store generated data from the QuizViewContoller to ScoreHistory? and how do I display the said data to the ScoreViewController?

My ScoreHistory looks like this:

```
class ScoreHistory: NSObject, NSCoding {

// MARK: Properties

var datePlayed: NSDate
var totalScore: Int
var totalAnswered: Int
var totalDuration: Int
var gameStatus: String

// MARK: Archiving Paths

static let DocumentsDirectory = NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("scores")

// MARK: Types

struct PropertyKey {
    static let datePlayedKey = "datePlayed"
    static let totalScoreKey = "totalScore"
    static let totalAnsweredKey = "totalAnswered"
    static let totalDurationKey = "totalDuration"
    static let gameStatusKey = "gameStatus"
}

// MARK: Initialization

init?(datePlayed: NSDate, totalScore: Int, totalAnswered: Int, totalDuration: Int, gameStatus: String) {
    // Initialize stored properties.

    self.datePlayed = datePlayed
    self.totalScore = totalScore
    self.totalAnswered = totalAnswered
    self.totalDuration = totalDuration
    self.gameStatus = gameStatus


    super.init()

    // Initialization should fail if there is no name or if the rating is negative.
    if gameStatus.isEmpty {
        return nil
    }
}

// MARK: NSCoding

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {

    aCoder.encodeObject(datePlayed, forKey: PropertyKey.datePlayedKey)
    aCoder.encodeInteger(totalScore, forKey: PropertyKey.totalScoreKey)
    aCoder.encodeInteger(totalAnswered, forKey: PropertyKey.totalAnsweredKey)
    aCoder.encodeInteger(totalDuration, forKey: PropertyKey.totalDurationKey)
    aCoder.encodeObject(gameStatus, forKey: PropertyKey.gameStatusKey)
}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    let datePlayed = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.datePlayedKey) as? NSDate
    let totalScore = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKey.totalScoreKey)
    let totalAnswered = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKey.totalAnsweredKey)
    let totalDuration = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKey.totalDurationKey)
    let gameStatus = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.gameStatusKey) as! String

    // Must call designated initializer.
    self.init(datePlayed: datePlayed!, totalScore: totalScore, totalAnswered: totalAnswered, totalDuration: totalDuration, gameStatus: gameStatus)
}

}
```

Comment: You are omitting the most important part of your class ScoreHistory where you are supposed to implement NSCoding coder and decoder

Comment: @LeoDabus, I updated my question, pls check

Comment: You could start changing the name of your file to scores.plist

Comment: like this? static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("score.plist")

Comment: Yes you will need also to use Keyed Archiver to convert your class  ScoreHistory object to NSData and save it

Comment: @LeoDabus, may you give me an overview on how these work together? I think I am "getting" the data or value from the `ScoreHistory` BUT the values are already generated in the `QuizViewController`.. How do I transfer the data from `QuizViewController` to store in `ScoreHistory`?

Comment: Store it to disk and read it from there

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSKeyedArchiver/archiveRootObject:toFile:

Comment: use `archiveRootObject(yourObject, path: yourURL.path!)`

Comment: to load use https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSKeyedUnarchiver/unarchiveObjectWithFile:

Comment: `unarchiveObjectWithFile(yourURL.path!) as? [ScoreHistory]`

Comment: I think you should name your class only Score since it represents a single score.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. Is your question:

1. How to store your score history to a file.
2. How to get changed information from one view controller to another view controller.

I can't figure it out based on the code you provided.

Answer to 1.
You correctly implemented the the NSCoding methods in the ScoreHistory class. I assume here that this is your model class that must hold the data that is collected throughout your game.
To save the data to a file you simply use the NSKeyedArchiver object. A sample of the code is:

```
    func saveStatisticsToDisk() {
    let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(savedScore, toFile: ScoreHistory.scoreStore.path!)

    if !isSuccessfulSave {
        //Set the alert properties.
        let title = "Warning"
        let message = "Unable to save the scores"
        let animationFlag = true

        //configure the alert.
        let alertMessage = UIAlertController.init(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default) {
            (action) -> Void in
            self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(animationFlag, completion: nil)
        }
        alertMessage.addAction(okAction)

        //Present the alert.
        self.presentViewController(alertMessage, animated: animationFlag, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer to 2.
This is more complicated, since you want to get data from one view controller to another view controller. Coding best practice tells that you should use NSNotifications to message changes from one view controller to the other. This is necessary to prevent strong reference cycles.

This means that in the QuizViewController you have an instance of the ScoreHistory class. Let's call it "quizScoreHistory". During the quiz the instance quizScoreHistory is update and when the player is finished with a level, or as you said: "after finishing a session", the ScoreViewController needs to know what the details of "quizScoreHistory" are, so it can display the information to the player.

I show you here how you can do this using a dictionary userInfo for a standard NSNotification.
In the class QuizViewController you use the follow code to place a notification in the default notification center:

```
    func notifyOnTrackChanges() {
//This function makes a dictionary with the key value pairs that reflect your ScoreHistory class.
//The a notification is posted under the name "scoreDidChange" posting the dictionary as userInfo. 
//The ScoreOverviewController will pick this up and store the values in the score to be displayed.

    let userInfo : [String: String] = ["date played": dateformatter.stringFromDate((self.quizScoreHistory.datePlayed)!), "total score": String((self.quizScoreHistory.totalScore)!), "total answered": String((self.quizScoreHistory.totalAnswered)!), "total duration": String((self.quizScoreHistory.gameStatus)!), "game status": String((self.quizScoreHistory.gameStatus)!)]
    let trackDetailNotificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    trackDetailNotificationCenter.postNotificationName("scoreDidChange", object: self, userInfo: userInfo)
}
```

I put the userInfo here as strings in a dictionary, since you only want to diaplay them in the ScoreViewController and understanding the code you provided you only need to get the score history as a string to display it in a cell.

Now you want to receive the notification in the ScoreViewController. This can be done to implement the following code in either the viewDidLoad, te viewWillAppear, or better write it as setter in your instance of the ScoreHistory.

```
        //This is the observer created to get the changes back from the QuizViewController.
    let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    let operationsQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
    self.scoreChangedObserver = notificationCenter.addObserverForName("scoreDidChange", object: nil, queue: operationsQueue, usingBlock: { (notification: NSNotification!) -> Void in

        let score.datePlayed = notification.userInfo!["date played"]!
        let score.totalScore = notification.userInfo!["total score"]!
        let score.totalAnswered = notification.userInfo!["total answered"]!
        let score.totalDuration = notification.userInfo!["total duration"]!
        let score.gameStatus = notification.userInfo!["gameStatus"]!

        self.displayScore()
    })
```

Your display score can then look like you provided in your question, assuming that the score is a property of the method:

```
func displayScore() {
    if let score = score {

        navigationItem.title = score.datePlayed
        datePlayedLabel.text = score.datePlayed
        totalScoreLabel.text   = score.totalScore
        totalAnsweredLabel.text   = score.totalAnswered
        totalDurationLabel.text   = score.totalDuration
        gameStatusLabel.text   = score.gameStatus
    }
}
```

I hope this helps in some way.